# How to add other info to the title page (e.g. class, professor)?

Tags: formatting, titles

I am new to LaTeX and trying to write my first paper with it. I need help on the title page. I want something that says

```
                               Initial Planning Report

                         Author 1 Author 2 Author 3 Author 4

                                       Class:

                                       Professor:

                                       Date:
```

I am able to make the 4 authors and the title. But when I try to add centered text under the authors' names, it only puts it under the 4th authors name. And also, is there a way I could have the authors be aligned vertically instead of horizontally?

Comment: Maybe you put your code here? Do you use `\maketitle` or the `titlepage` environment?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may use the `titlepage` environment.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage[charter]{mathdesign}
%-----------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
% ----------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{titlepage}
\begin{center}
 {\Huge\bfseries Initial Planning Report\\}
 % ----------------------------------------------------------------
 \vspace{2cm}
 {\Large\bfseries Author -- 1}\\[5pt]
 email@gmail.com\\[14pt]
 {\Large\bfseries Author -- 2}\\[5pt]
 email@gmail.com\\[14pt]
 {\Large\bfseries Author -- 3}\\[5pt]
 email@gmail.com\\[14pt]
 {\Large\bfseries Author -- 4}\\[5pt]
 email@gmail.com\\[14pt]
 % ----------------------------------------------------------------
 \vspace{2cm}
 % ----------------------------------------------------------------
 \begin{list}{}{
        \setlength{\leftmargin}{1.5in}
        \setlength{\labelwidth}{0pt}
        \setlength{\labelsep}{1in}
            \setlength{\itemsep}{15pt}}
            \raggedright
    \item[\hbox to 0pt{\Large\bfseries Class:}]      {}
        \item[\hbox to 0pt{\Large\bfseries Professor:}]      {}
        \item[\hbox to 0pt{\Large\bfseries Date:}]      {}
 \end{list}
\end{center}
\end{titlepage}
% ----------------------------------------------------------------
\end{document}
% ----------------------------------------------------------------
```

[image]

Comment: How would I get those last pieces of information such as Class, Professor, and date to center?

Comment: @GregHarrington you can adjust the left margin in `\setlength{\leftmargin}{1.5in}` suitably.